# ajax jquery does not return select query results

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

So, I have a textfield n my view file that gets the employee code and jquery calls a function in the controller for employees details to fill in some fields in the same view page immediately. But I am stock and nothing is really happening, see in my codes and help me do it.
Thank you!

jquery:

```
$('#employee_code').change(function(){  
    var em_code = $('#employee_code').val();
    if (em_code != ""){
        var post_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/it_inventory/get_employee_details/" + em_code;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: post_url,
            success: function(name,position,department) 
            {
                $('#employee_name').val(name);
                $('#employee_position').val(position);
                $('#employee_department').val(department);
            }
        }); 
    }          
});
```

CI controller:

```
function get_employee_details($em_code="") {
        header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
        echo(json_encode($this->it_inventory_model->get_employee_details($em_code)));
    }
```

CI Model

```
function get_employee_details($em_code){
        $q = "select name,position,department from employees where code=?";
        $query_em_detail=$this->db->query($q,$em_code);

        $outputs = array();

        if($query_em_detail->result()){
            foreach ($query_em_detail->result() as $output) {
                $outputs['name'] = $output->name;
                $outputs['position'] = $output->position;
                $outputs['department'] = $output->department_code;
            }
            return $outputs;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I pass the employee code via url "http://localhost/it_inventory/index.php/it_inventory/get_employee_details/11330", it outputs the correct data starting to download in text format file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `dataType` in your ajax request, like:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: post_url,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); //response from your controller
      console.log( data.name); //to get name
   },
   error: function() { alert("Something went wrong!"); }
});
```

and controller:

```
function get_employee_details($em_code="") {
  header('Content-Type: application/json',true);
  echo(json_encode($this->it_inventory_model->get_employee_details($em_code)));
}
```

Comment: Seems to have no effect on what I want, sudhir!

Comment: what do you see in console for ajax request..? do you see proper data or any error ..?

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont know how do I see if anything is returned in console or ?? but as I said it returns the correct data when passing employee code to the function in controller via url

Comment: if you're using mozilla browser then check on your firebug console for ajax request, F12 key would show the firebug..

Comment: Ohh, yesss, It worked, the problem was a silly typo, in my view file causing the output not to show up in the correct field.

Answer (score 0):

I think `success: function(name,position,department)` should be `success: function(result)`. Then you need to use `result.name`, `result.position` etc

```
success: function(result) {
    $('#employee_name').val(result.name);
    $('#employee_position').val(result.position);
    $('#employee_department').val(result.department);
}
```